Bundling executable binary for each platform with electron-forge
I would like to bundle pandoc executable binary for each platform (for Windows, macOS, Linux) in my electron app using electron-forge.
I want to contain the binary in bin directory.
How I can configured it?
My host computer is Arch Linux and electron 31.
.
├── README.md
├── bin -- I want to contain binary for each platform.  
│   ├── linux
│   ├── macos
│   └── win
├── forge.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── index.html
    ├── main.js
    ├── preload.js
    ├── render.js
    └── style.css

